# expected "indent", got "outdent" after function

Tags: stylus

I'm trying to implement function

```
children(nums,step)
 int=0.7
 int2=0.5
 for num in nums
  $ttime=int+step*(num-2);
  $tdel=$ttime+int2
  .catalog li.lvl1:hover>ul li.lvl2:nth-child({num})
   transition visibility ease-out {$ttime}s {$tdel}s
   visibility visible
```

and get this eror

```
111|  .catalog li.lvl1:hover>ul li.lvl2:nth-child({num})
   112|   transition visibility ease-out {$ttime}s {$tdel}s
   113|   visibility visible
   114| 
   115| .other,.contacts,.catalog
--------^
   116|  border-left 7px solid $rcolr
   117|  padding-left: 2.8%;
   118| 

   expected "indent", got "outdent"

   at Parser.error     (/usr/local/nodejs/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/parser.js:257:11)
```

it seems that parser consider the rest of the code to be a part of function.
What misteke i made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use interpolation inside values of properties. This code should work:

```
children(nums,step)
 int=0.7
 int2=0.5
 for num in nums
  $ttime=int+step*(num - 2);
  $tdel=$ttime+int2
  .catalog li.lvl1:hover>ul li.lvl2:nth-child({num})
    transition visibility ease-out ($ttime)s ($tdel)s
    visibility visible
```

Comment: thanks a lot! That solved! But my vorking variant is this

    for num in 2..5
    step=0.3s
    int=0.7s
    int2=0.5s
    ttime=int+step*(num - 2)
    $tdel=ttime + int2
    .catalog li.lvl1:hover>ul li.lvl2:nth-child({num})
      transition visibility ease-out ttime $tdel
      visibility visible